# Packaged version of Torch for neural networks

Tags: neural-network, torch

I tried installing Torch and the `nn` package with a view to carrying out some experiments on neural networks, but the recommended procedure failed with a compile error while trying to install the latter. The procedure involves taking some git snapshots, so there is some degree of non-determinism.

Does there exist a package of Torch and `nn` snapshotted from known compatible versions, such that you could apply the package to Ubuntu X.Y and it would always work (or always fail, as the case may be)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Torch website:

*Torch can be installed to your home folder in ~/torch by running these three commands:*

```
# in a terminal, run the commands
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; ./install.sh
```

*The first script installs the basic package dependencies that LuaJIT and Torch require. The second script installs LuaJIT, LuaRocks, and then uses LuaRocks (the lua package manager) to install core packages like torch, nn and paths, as well as a few other packages.*

I've installed Torch a few times now and found this most successful - no compilation required.

Comment: Okay, it worked when I retried, so must have been a transient error.